# How do I wrap a command in a yes/no msg?

Tags: vbscript

I'd like to condition the following code into a yes/no, maybe even a timed "yes" (default) of 10 seconds. I've looked around, and I found some answers, but I unfortunately do not have access to a test environment which would allow me quick results.

My vbs is:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmd = "%comspec% /c diskpart /s X:\cleandisk.txt"
objShell.Run cmd,1,1    ' Run the command in a window and wait for a return
```

I'd like to be able to prompt to either run or bypass this. The context is an MDT environment. The purpose is to wipe the disk prior to imaging. Unfortunately, it runs all the time, and when I go to capture an image, it wipes the drive (oops). So instead of over complicating with the limited resources, a simple yes/no to run it or not is my situation's best bet.

As an option, I'd like to have a 10 second countdown timer on the default "yes" answer.

As I mentioned earlier, I'm not adverse to figuring it out myself, but I have limited resources (vbs editos, test environment, etc.) for this at work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Popup` method.

```
Dim objShell: Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Select Case objShell.Popup("Run this? Will autorun in 10 seconds!", 10, "Title", 1)
Case -1 
    'Timed Out
Case 1
    'OK Pressed
Case 2
    'Cancel Pressed
End Select
```

### Return Values

- `-1` Value: The MsgBox timed out. You can combine this with case 1 since you want these to perform the same action (see below)
- `1` Value: The user pressed the 'OK' button
- `2` Value: The user pressed the 'Cancel' button

---

Since you want to treat a timeout the same way as the user pressing 'OK', you can combine the two values into one case:

```
Dim objShell: Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'                                               This is the timeout ↓↓ 
Select Case objShell.Popup("Run this? Will autorun in 10 seconds!", 10, "Title", 1)
Case -1, 1
    cmd = "%comspec% /c diskpart /s X:\cleandisk.txt"
    objShell.Run cmd,1,1
Case 2
    ' Do nothing
End Select
```